# Twitter API: Get Access Token without sending username/password

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am having a **problem obtaining the twitter users access token and secret token without sending a username and password**. I would like to get the access token by just sending the twitter_id, once the user has already authenticated my application before.

**So the scenario is:**

A user logs into my site (using custom login), he already gave my application permission to read/write his tweets. Now I need to load this users access token and secret access token.

```
Database:
CustomUID : 1 , Twitter_ID: 123456.
```

So Since I know  CustomUID 1 is logged in, I need the access token/secret from Twitter_ID:123456.

The **Problem** is I can´t find an API function that would let me get the access token without being **redirect to Twitter Callback** function (Twitter landing page), where the user has to type in his/her username and password, once again because the Request Tokens are obtained by the URL.

How can I solve this problem? I am used to the Facebook API, where user which have already authorize my app, allow me to receive their accesstoken just bei sending **getAccessToken($ID)**.

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: The only way I see is, to save the AccessToken and SecretToken in my database when the user gives my app the permission for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save, possibly in your DB, the OAuth token and access token after the first time the user authenticates. Then retrieve the token the next time you need to perform a query on behalf of that user.

Comment: Ye, that is what I was talking about. I found out I have to save it in the DB.